# If $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dots, \alpha^n, \dots$ are linearly dependent, then, there exists a finite subset which is linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dots, \alpha^n, \dots$ are linearly dependent over a field ($K$) then this means that there exists $I \subset \mathbb{N}$, $ |I| < \infty$ such that ${ (\alpha_i) }_{i \in I}$ are linearly dependent?

What I've tried:
For a infinite set, linearly independent means that every finite subset is linearly independent. So, suppose no finite subset of $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dots, \alpha^n, \dots $ is linearly dependent $\implies$ all finite subsets are linearly independent, so $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dots, \alpha^n, \dots$ is linearly independent, which is contradiction. So, there exists $I \subset \mathbb{N}$, $ |I| < \infty$ such that $(\alpha_i)_{i \in I}$ are linearly dependent. Are the statement and the proof true? Thanks!

Comment: The question is just the contrapositive of the definition. It is true for all lists of vectors, not only $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,...$